# No files found for KieBase defaultKieBase - Drool-8.33.0.Final

Tags: drools

[xls format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5o5z.png)`I am developing a spring boot restful service which need to use the Business Rule Management System. I have chosen the drools. Chosen the latest version.
I am using spring boot 2.7.7 version, drools version 8.33.0.Final & java 17 version.

Issue: I am not able to process the rules when I add in the .xlsx or .xls or .csv format.
I have tried with different options, but not working with .xlsx or .xls or .csv format. Any suggestion is welcome.

Warning error message in console:

> No files found for KieBase defaultKieBase

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
    <groupId>com.codeusingjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>boot-drools</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>boot-drools</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <drools.version>8.33.0.Final</drools.version>
        <!-- <drools.version>8.15.0.Beta</drools.version> -->
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-mvel</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Drools Configuration:

```
import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieBuilder;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieFileSystem;
import org.kie.api.builder.KieModule;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.internal.io.ResourceFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class DroolsConfiguration {

    private final KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

    @Bean
    public KieContainer kieContainer() {
        KieContainer kieCont = null;

        try {
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
        kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("rules/discount.xlsx"));
        KieBuilder kb = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
        kb.buildAll();
        KieModule kieModule = kb.getKieModule();
        kieCont = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());
        
        }catch(Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return kieCont;
    }
}
```

DepositRateCalculator.java

```
package com.codeusingjava.bootdrools.controller;

import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.codeusingjava.bootdrools.model.DepositRequest;

@RestController
public class DepositRateController {

    @Autowired
    private KieContainer kieContainer;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getInterestRate", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public String getInterest(@RequestParam(required = true) String loanType,
            @RequestParam(required = true) Integer durationInYear, @RequestParam(required = true) Integer age) {
        KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
        DepositRequest depositRequest = new DepositRequest(loanType, durationInYear, age);
        kieSession.insert(depositRequest);
        kieSession.fireAllRules();
        kieSession.dispose();
        return "The interest rate for this application is " + depositRequest.getInterestRate();
    }
}
```

DepositRequest.java

```
package com.codeusingjava.bootdrools.model;

public class DepositRequest {
    private String loanType;
    private Integer durationInYear;
    private Integer age;
    private String interestRate;

    public DepositRequest(String loanType, Integer durationInYear, Integer age) {
        super();
        this.loanType = loanType;
        this.durationInYear = durationInYear;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getLoanType() {
        return loanType;
    }

    public void setLoanType(String loanType) {
        this.loanType = loanType;
    }

    public Integer getDurationInYear() {
        return durationInYear;
    }

    public void setDurationInYear(Integer durationInYear) {
        this.durationInYear = durationInYear;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getInterestRate() {
        return interestRate;
    }

    public void setInterestRate(String interestRate) {
        this.interestRate = interestRate;
    }

}
```

Console:

```
Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-02-17 13:20:01.551  INFO 19264 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-02-17 13:20:01.551  INFO 19264 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.70]
2023-02-17 13:20:01.955  INFO 19264 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-02-17 13:20:01.955  INFO 19264 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1006 ms
**2023-02-17 13:20:02.891  WARN 19264 --- [  restartedMain] o.d.c.kie.builder.impl.KieProject        : No files found for KieBase defaultKieBase
2023-02-17 13:20:03.073  INFO 19264 --- [**  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-02-17 13:20:03.099  INFO 19264 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-02-17 13:20:03.105  INFO 19264 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.bootdrools.BootDroolsApplication     : Started BootDroolsApplication in 2.433 seconds (JVM running for 3.26)`
```

Tested URL: localhost:8080/getInterestRate?loanType=Fixed&age=45&durationInYear=1

Comment: you should consider Kogito on SpringBoot instead of trying to manually wire a KB inside your SB.

Comment: Why aren't you using a kmodule xml and letting it get wired up automatically? Then your container bean definition is as simple as `KieServices.Factory.get().getClasspathContainer()` ...

Comment: this approach is working until drool 7.x.x version. Here I am trying with drools 8.33.0.Final version. Using the same implementation it is working for rules defined in .drl file, when I am trying to use rules define in .csv or .xlsx or .xls I am getting the issue. Not working..

Answer (score 2):

[Please refer the Documentation](https://docs.drools.org/8.37.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/release-notes/index.html#_spreadsheet_decision_tables_file_extensions)

According to the Docs we should name the excel file with extension ***.drl.xlsx**. This worked for me.